# Marsaglia's XorShift compareAndSet Thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, random

I have some problems to make a safety PRNG (Marsaglia's XorShift), in theory the serie of values generated have to be the same for each execution. But it's not my case and don't know why. I have to use `compareAndSet`for the Thread Safety.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```java
package fr.umlv.conc;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class RandomTest {
  private AtomicLong z = new AtomicLong();

  public RandomTest(long seed) {
    if (seed == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("seed == 0");
    }
    this.z = new AtomicLong(seed);
  }

  public long next() {
      // Marsaglia's XorShift
      AtomicLong seed = this.z;
      long oldseed, nextseed;
      do {
            oldseed = seed.get();
            nextseed = xorShift(oldseed);
          } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return nextseed * 2685821657736338717L;
  }

private long xorShift(long x) {
    x ^= x >>> 12;
    x ^= x << 25;
    x ^= x >>> 27;

    return x;
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                 RandomTest rng = new RandomTest(1);
                 for(int j = 0; j < 5_000; j++) {
                     System.out.println(rng.next());
                 }
            });
            t.start();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you verify the results are different?

Comment: Actually there was more than that, I just realized. I can post and explain what I have in mind but a first question I would have is why do you need multiple threads to generate your sequence? In this case, given the work to do for each call of `next()` is lightweight and your requirement to guarantee the order of occurrence of each number, I don't think multithreading can help.

Comment: In fact, firstly I have the same programs without threads and AtomicLong, it just generate PRN values, but then I had to make it thread safety with compareAndSet, so i wanted to test if with multithreading I can generate the same serie several times.

Comment: Looks like the code is not accessing the same instance concurrently at all. What's the point?

Comment: That's what im thinking, it's an exercise of multithreading and the principe of Atomic field (and Varhandle), it was asked to make the generator "lock-free" (so without ```synchronized```and ```lock```) with compareAndSet and after to use VarHandle. So firstly i was thinking to create mutiple threads to generate the serie and use ```compareAndSet``` to prevent other thread from modifying ```x```

Comment: Probably you need to adjust the code to run two scenarios:  (1) with a single thread accessing one instance and (2) with many threads accessing a shared instance with the same seed as in (1). Then you would verify that results are identical (provided number of values produced is the same in both runs).